# Счетчик неправильно считает элемента в таблице со слитыми рядами

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Есть таблица, в начале каждого ряда которой есть чекбокс. При клике на этот чекбокс открывается блок-меню.

Но когда ряды частично слиты атрибутом rowspan, то счетчик неправильно считает чекбоксы, из-за чего открываются неверные меню.

В случае когда нет атрибута rowspan, клик на чекбокс открывает меню в соседней ячейке таблицы. 
Но когда строки слиты rowspan, то при клике на чекбоксы, которые находятся ниже слитого ряда, открывается не меню в соседней клетке, а два меню - в соседней и нижней.

[image: баг в таблице]
[image: баг в таблице]

Код https://jsfiddle.net/kaintz/Lcmtezpv/14/

```js
//чекбоксы
var countSelectedCheckBox = 0;

$("#table-head-check").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { // если класса нет
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // добавляем класс
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    $($('div.settings-user')).hide();
    $($('#settings-user-head')).show();
    countSelectedCheckBox = $("input:checkbox:checked").length - 1;
    // countSelectedCheckBox=999; // устанавливаем большое значение, чтобы после клика в шапке выделить все
    //не появлялась строка редактирования для каждой строки
  } else { // если есть
    $(this).removeClass('clicked'); // убираем класс
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#minus-head').css('backgroundImage', 'unset');
    $($('#settings-user-head')).hide();
    countSelectedCheckBox = 0;
  }
  console.log(countSelectedCheckBox);
})

$('input.ShowOrHide').click(function(e) {
  //считаес сколько чекбоксов выбрано
  if (this.checked) {
    countSelectedCheckBox++;
  } else {
    countSelectedCheckBox--;
  };
  console.log(countSelectedCheckBox);
  //если выбрано больше одного, то прячем для всех польхователей строку редактирования\
  //и добавляем строку редактирования в шапку
  if (countSelectedCheckBox > 1) {
    $($('div.settings-user')).hide();
    $($('#settings-user-head')).show();
    $('#minus-head').css('backgroundImage', 'url(img/remove.svg)');
  } //Если выбран один или не выбрано пользователей, то прячем редактирование в шапке
  else {
    $($('#settings-user-head')).hide();
    //ищем выбранный чекбокс и ближаюший блок с панелью редактирования для него и показываем
    $("input:checkbox:checked").parents('td').siblings('td').find('.settings-user').show();
    $('#table-head-check').removeAttr("checked");
    $('#minus-head').css('backgroundImage', 'unset');
  }
  if (countSelectedCheckBox < $("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
    $('#table-head-check').prop('checked', false);
    $('#minus-head').css('backgroundImage', 'url(img/remove.svg)');
  }
  var indexOfElement = $(this).parents('tr').index();
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'table-head-check') {

  } else {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && countSelectedCheckBox <= 1) {

      $($('div.settings-user')[indexOfElement + 1]).show();
    } else {
      $($('div.settings-user')[indexOfElement + 1]).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox label.i-checks {
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #aab8ce;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.checkbox .i-checks input[type="checkbox"]  {
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
    transition: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox .i-checks > i {
    border: 1px solid #bdc7d8;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 17px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkbox .i-checks input:checked + i::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/447/447147.png);
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 18px;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
}

.settings-user{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 11px;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    width: max-content;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.settings-user a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-right: 35px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 15px;
    
}
```

```html
<table class="table-rating" id="allUsers">
  <thead class="ff-b">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="table-head-check">
                <i id="minus-head"></i>
              </label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="settings-user" id="settings-user-head">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Удалить</a>
        </div>
        ФИО</th>
      <th>Специализация</th>
      <th>Телефон</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                    <i></i>
                </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <div class="settings-user">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
        </div>
        Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
      <td rowspan="2">HR</td>
      <td rowspan="2">+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
      <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                  <i></i>
              </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="settings-user">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
        </div>
        Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
      <td>HR</td>
      <td>+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
      <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label class="i-checks">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                    <i></i>
                </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="settings-user">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
        </div>
        Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
      <td>HR</td>
      <td>+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
      <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Можно ли исправить эту ситуацию? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Что конкретно у вашем примере работает не верно?

Comment: Не совсем понятна логика переключений, но в качестве [примера](https://jsfiddle.net/rusiq/qurv4jpk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не понятно что имели введу - посмотрите может так.

```js
//чекбоксы
  var countSelectedCheckBox = 0;

  $("#table-head-check").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { // если класса нет
      $(this).addClass('clicked'); // добавляем класс
      $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
      $($('div.settings-user')).hide();
      $($('#settings-user-head')).show();
      countSelectedCheckBox = $("input:checkbox:checked").length - 1;
      // countSelectedCheckBox=999; // устанавливаем большое значение, чтобы после клика в шапке выделить все
      //не появлялась строка редактирования для каждой строки
    } else { // если есть
      $(this).removeClass('clicked'); // убираем класс
      $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
      $('#minus-head').css('backgroundImage', 'unset');
      $($('#settings-user-head')).hide();
      countSelectedCheckBox = 0;
    }
    console.log(countSelectedCheckBox);
  });

    $("#allUsers tbody tr").each((i, tr) => {
     $(tr).find(".ShowOrHide").click((e) => {
      let settingsUser = $(tr).find("div.settings-user");

      if ($(e.target).prop("checked")) {
       countSelectedCheckBox++;
       $(settingsUser).show();
      } else {
       countSelectedCheckBox--;
       $(settingsUser).hide();
      }

      //console.log(countSelectedCheckBox);
     });
    });
```

```css
body {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  th, td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
  }

  .checkbox label.i-checks {
      padding-left: 15px;
      color: #aab8ce;
      font-size: 16px;
  }
  .checkbox .i-checks input[type="checkbox"]  {
      border-radius: 3px;
      box-shadow: none;
      float: left;
      transition: none;
      opacity: 0;
  }
  .checkbox .i-checks > i {
      border: 1px solid #bdc7d8;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 17px;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: 13px;
      margin-top: -2px;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 17px;
      border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .checkbox .i-checks input:checked + i::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
      background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/447/447147.png);
      height: 17px;
      width: 17px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 18px;
      top: -5px;
      right: -5px;
  }

  .settings-user{
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      background: blue;
      z-index: 10;
      top: 11px;
      height: calc(100% - 20px);
      width: max-content;
      padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .settings-user a {
      text-decoration: underline;
      margin-right: 35px;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      color: #fff;
      padding-left: 15px;
      
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-rating" id="allUsers">
   <thead class="ff-b">
     <tr>
       <th>
         <div class="checkbox">
           <label class="i-checks">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="table-head-check">
                 <i id="minus-head"></i>
               </label>
         </div>
       </th>
       <th>
         <div class="settings-user" id="settings-user-head">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Удалить</a>
         </div>
         ФИО</th>
       <th>Специализация</th>
       <th>Телефон</th>
       <th>Email</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">
         <div class="checkbox">
           <label class="i-checks">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                     <i></i>
                 </label>
         </div>
       </td>
       <td rowspan="2">
         <div class="settings-user">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
         </div>
         Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
       <td rowspan="2">HR</td>
       <td rowspan="2">+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
       <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
           <label class="i-checks">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                   <i></i>
               </label>
         </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <div class="settings-user">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
         </div>
         Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
       <td>HR</td>
       <td>+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
       <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <div class="checkbox">
           <label class="i-checks">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ShowOrHide">
                <i></i>
            </label>
         </div>
       </td>
       <td>
         <div class="settings-user">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal">Снять права</a>
         </div>
         Поляков Андрей Владимирович</td>
       <td>HR</td>
       <td>+375 (29) 767-99-04</td>
       <td>orlov@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Я конечно тот еще мастер в формулировании вопросов. Поправила формулировку. Но Ваше решение это именно то что нужно. Спасибо огромное!